# In Snow Crash, could "crashed" hackers be healed?

Tags: snow-crash

Spoilers:

In Stephenson's excellent Snow Crash,

> Da5id's brain is "crashed" with the Snow Crash virus. Later, the inhabitants of the raft are "rebooted" with the nam-shub of Enki...

Could this be used to heal him, or was he just screwed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is never addressed overtly in the book, but my impression is that it's very likely that the Nam-Shub would do the trick. Additionally, my assumption is that if the Nam-Shub itself is not sufficient to restore Da5id's health, Juanita's newfound abilities as a ba'al-shem would be able to perform a more surgical fix.

Comment: Good point! I'd forgotten about that. Presumably as long as the hardware isn't too damaged, she can patch the software...

Comment: A lot of it depends on if the data is scrambled, or if the harddrive was formatted and overwritten with random patterns of 1s and 0s...

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that Da5id was permanently brain-damaged. However, in my "head canon," I like to imagine that he eventually woke up, but thought he was a Sumerian god, and started a cult.

As for the others, they were only brainwashed, not turned into vegetables, so I think they might be salvageable.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE.  Head canon is exactly what this site *is not* about.  We seek answers based on sources that can be referenced.  It's easy to confuse this site for a discussion forum.  I encourage you to browse through highly-voted past answers to see examples of what we're looking for.  We hope you stick around and contribute.  :-)